# external css works fine on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: html, css, docker, google-chrome, nginx

I deployed a simple webpage index.html with a simple stylesheet on to docker/nginx .

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">     
  <title>FlexBox</title>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="container">
  <div>Home</div>
  <div>Search</div>
  <div>Logout</div>
</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

mystyle.css

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

when I load the index.html from server I can see(f12) the css file is being pulled from server, but not applied. If I make a change to the css file like adding a space through the f12/developer tool, the stylesheet is applied.

ps: When I view the webpage from liveserver in vscode locally it is working fine. no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue was with the Nginx conf to specify mime type for css

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```